# Cassandra convert Token to long

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I wanna run a query like this on a table:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE token(_id) >= -9220405531215751472 AND token(_id) < -9215701564955960000 AND state=true ALLOW FILTERING;
```

I read range of tokens by `metadata.getTokenMap()` and then `tokenMap.getTokenRanges()`. But it gives me start and end token as Token Object (e.g. *Murmur3Token(9187337865070158013)*
)! How I can convert it to **long** or **String** to use in query:

```
CqlSession session = builder.build();

Metadata metadata = session.getMetadata();
if (metadata.getTokenMap().isPresent()) {

   TokenMap tokenMap = metadata.getTokenMap().get();

   for(TokenRange range : tokenMap.getTokenRanges()) {

          System.out.println(range.getStart()); // output Murmur3Token(9187337865070158013)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how I can convert it! It must be converted to `Murmur3Token` explicitly and call `getValue` method.

```
long start,end;
String sql;

for(TokenRange range : tokenMap.getTokenRanges()) {
    start = ((Murmur3Token) range.getStart()).getValue();
    end = ((Murmur3Token) range.getEnd()).getValue();
    sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE token(_id) >= "+start+" AND token(_id) < "+end+" AND state=true ALLOW FILTERING;";
    System.out.println(i +":" + sql);
}
```

Comment: here is example that is doing what you want to do, but correctly: https://github.com/alexott/cassandra-dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/TokenRangesScan.java#L38 - your code doesn't handle the token range overlap, so you'll miss some data

Comment: you can search in my answers - I described how it should work somewhere

Comment: Would you please to comment URL here! I did not find.